# NamedParameterStatement - Oracle

Tags: oracle

Is it possible to use two NamedParameterStatement for a single query?

I need to find the ids (Primary and foreign key) for the given value using one NamedParameterStatement, and then all other details related to the ids from other tables.

for example

```
select code1, code2 code 3

from master table where id in (select id from master table where (date between or any other values))
```

**The description for other codes are in other table**

Here I need to pass the result of inner query to the outer query ( I may get the  many ids). And I know how to pass the result to another query in JDBC?

Comment: Why do you need to do it as two separate queries? What's the problem with using a single query with an `IN` as you've shown, and calling the whole thing as a single query over JDBC?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Alex. I used a single query to obtain the result.